# Problem renaming wireless interfaces

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I want to rename a wireless interface. Right now I have 4 network interfaces, 2 Wireless, 2 Cable. the order is like this:

eth0 - Cable (Realtek RTL-8169)
eth1 - Cable (Intel 82579V)
eth2 - Wireless (Broadcom BCM4321 Proprietary Drivers)
wlan0 - Wireless (RaLink RT2800)

I want to rename eth2 to wlan1. This way the wireless cards are wlan and the cable ones are eth (The way I like it). How can I do this?

Using the suggestion made by virpara I found the following:

eth1 - e1000e
wlan0 - rt2800
wlan1 - b43
eth2 - wl

```
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="38:60:77:ab:5e:30", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x1814:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0 (rt2800pci)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:9c:05:fd:28", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/ssb0:0 (b43-pci-bridge)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:18:39:0e:f0:ff", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:18:39:0e:f0:ff", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
```

Now my questions are:

1. Why wlan1 and eth2 have the same MAC?
2. If there are 2 duplicated MACS (eth2 & wlan1) where is the other NIC?
3. Why is Realtek (eth0) not appearing on the list?
4. Where did wlan1 come from since I can not see it using `ifconfig -a`, `iwconfig` or `lshw`. There is no wlan1 except in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file.

Comment: Sorry not talking about the name of an interface connection. I am talking about the interface name.

Comment: `ifconfig -a` what does it give?

Comment: It gives the first list I mentioned. I got it from there then did a lshw -c network to know which name was associated with what card. But the confusion to rename began with your answer.

Comment: Can you pastebin output of `lshw -c network`, and/or let us know which devices you installed in your system -- i.e. why you have two 802.11 ifaces?

Comment: Actually the first ones I mentioned are what the lshw output and ifconfig -a give me. I just summarized them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to reorder or rename logical interface names in Linux

http://www.science.uva.nl/research/air/wiki/LogicalInterfaceNames

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/62716

http://wishmesh.com/2009/09/ubuntu-server-rename-eth1-to-eth0/

Answer (score 3):

See the comment at the beginning of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`:

```
 # Entries are automatically added by the 75-persistent-net-generator.rules
 # file; however you are also free to add your own entries.
```

That is an auto-generated (and possibly customized file).

`/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` is where all the action takes place. It's hard to tell right now which entries are auto and which were added by you or some other application.

Try renaming `70-.....` to an extension that is not `.rules` (or move to another directory). Then reboot, and paste the content of the "clean generated" 70-persistent-net.rules.

Comment: Doing that threw me the same file.

Answer (score 2):

`gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

you will have content as,

```
# This file maintains persistent names for network interfaces.
# See udev(7) for syntax.
#
# Entries are automatically added by the 75-persistent-net-generator.rules
# file; however you are also free to add your own entries.

# PCI device 0x11ab:0x4357 (sky2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:b3:7b:28:3d", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x4222 (iwl3945)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1f:3c:e0:f2:45", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

make changes accordingly in `NAME=`

Comment: Going to update my question using your info here. There is something weird about this maybe you can answer the questions.