# wlan0 interface disappeared after upgrade to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, network-manager, intel-wireless

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and now the wlan0 interface is gone from `ifconfig`. Instead, it shows a weird interface called **enxbe3baf6373f3**...

```
enxbe3baf6373f3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:3b:af:63:73:f3  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:13520 (13.5 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:f4:bb:86:82:f5  
      inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::eef4:bbff:fe86:82f5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12803786 (12.8 MB)  TX bytes:1178445 (1.1 MB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:157958 (157.9 KB)  TX bytes:157958 (157.9 KB)
```

My Wireless hardware is an Intel 7260, which is reknown for having compatibility issues... actually in the past I had an issue which I solved by installing the most recent iwlwifi firmware. Today I did the same: `modinfo iwlwifi` shows that the kernel loads the version 12. So, after backing it up, I replaced it with the version 15.

Still, wlan0 is not showing and the issue did not change a bit...

Oh, I am running the kernel 4.2.0-16-generic.

Also, `rfkill list all` results in the following

```
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

And, of course, both `ifup wlan0` and `ifdown wlan0` gave the following: `Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.`

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Please let me know if I can make this question more complete by adding the output of any command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
[rename interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142731/problem-renaming-wireless-interfaces)

```
sudo kate /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

replace "kate" with "gedit","nano" or your favourite editor and add the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="be:3b:af:63:73:f3", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

In my case wireless was working (had to use external driver/firmware) ,but I noticed many error logs on "syslog" and had to rename it.

Comment: The line is already there... :/